# Geometrical construction of circle and circumscription of a pentagon about it.

Tags: geometric-construction

How would you draw a circle of a given radius and circumscribe a regular pentagon about it using a scale and a compass. I cannot figure it out. I have checked the internet but cannot find anything valuable. Most of the sites are dealing with inscribed pentagons while the rest say to use a protractor.

Comment: The site which you have mentioned deals with inscribed pentagons not circumscribed pentagons.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Just realized that.  [Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Circumscribing_Regular_Pentagon_about_Circle) is a reference that deals with circumscribed pentagons.  It starts with the inscribed pentagon and is rather simple from there.